# How can I use the json tag in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I have been using TDengine with fixed tag schema for while. The newest version of TDengine seems to support tags of json, which can represent tags with different fields. How can I use it and how should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.taosdata.com/docs/cn/v2.0/connector#json here.

Create a table with json tag:

```sql
# create stable
create stable s1 (ts timestamp, v1 int) tags (info json);
# create sub table
create table s1_1 using s1 tags ('{\"k1\": \"v1\"}');
```

Get json data

```sql
select tbname, info from s1
# s1 | '{"k1":"v1"}'
```

Query key 'k1':

```sql
select info->'k1' as k1 from s1;
select info->'k1' as k1 from s1 where info->'k1' = 'v1';
```